# Como gerar variáveis correlacionados no R?

Tags: r, rnorm, números-aleatórios

Eu consegui criar as variáveis uniformes `X` e `W`, ambas com distribuição normal, através da fórmula `rnorm` no `R`. Porém, eu queria criar as variáveis de forma que eles tivessem um valor -0.8 de correlação.

Qual comando utilizado para isso??

Comment: Eu não sendo um entusiasta 100% em R, creio que esses dois posts resolvam seu problema(estão em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826793/create-correlated-variables-from-existing-variable e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047033/r-constructing-correlated-variables/17049940#17049940.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há pelo menos duas formas de se fazer isso:

1. Como as duas variáveis são Normais, pode-se usar a função `mvrnorm()` do pacote `MASS`.
2. Outra opção é seguir essas instruções:

   ```
   # gerar dois vetores N(0,1), independentes
   z1 = rnorm(100)
   z2 = rnorm(100)

   rho = -0.8  # o coeficiente de correlacao

   e1 = z1
   e2 = rho*z1+sqrt(1-rho^2)*z2

   cor(e1,e2)  # aproximadamente -0.8
   ```

Note contudo que deve-se adaptar a solução 2 caso queira-se que os vetores `e1` e `e2` tenham médias diferentes de 0.

A pergunta original não deixa claro se os vetores `X` e `W` seguem a distribuição uniforme ou a normal; a minha resposta assume que seja o 2o caso.