# Criando uma matriz com variaveis com correlacoes diferentes no R?

Tags: r, loop, matriz

Preciso gerar séries de dados que possuem correlações definidas usando o R. Utilizei um método que encontrei aqui no SO ([Como gerar variáveis correlacionados no R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10214/como-gerar-variaveis-correlacionados-no-r)) e consegui criar as variáveis com a correlação desejada, no entanto, ao tentar automatizar este processo para a criação de 1000 estimações e para correlações diferentes, o resultado obtido é uma matriz 1000x5 com todos os valores idênticos. O código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
set.seed(2423049)
corr = matrix(,1000,5) 
for(k in 1:5){
  for (i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:1000){
rho = c(-0.7,-0.3,0,0.1,0.5) # correlações que preciso utilizar

xstar=rnorm(1000,2,2) # x* com distribuicao normal N(2,2)

a2=rnorm(1000,2,2) # parametro criado para obter w a partir da correlacao rho com x*

w = rho[k]*xstar+sqrt(1-rho[k]^2)*a2 # w calculado a partir de uma correlacao definida com x

corr[j,i]=cor(xstar,w) # matriz de correlacoes entre x* e w
  }
 }
}
```

Através deste processo, o resultado obtido foi uma matriz 1000x5 onde todos os valores eram 0.5499732

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedro,

Primeiramente, você tem um loop a mais no seu código. Note que você está gerando uma matriz 1000 por 5. Aí você começa um loop por `k` (correlações), depois por `i` (colunas), e depois por `j` (linhas). Veja que  você roda para cada `k` as 5 colunas e as 1000 linhas, isto é, a cada `k` você está escrevendo por cima de todos os resultados anteriores. Então ao final você só vai gravar os resultados do último `k` (`rho=0.5`) na matriz.

Para evitar este problema o loop deveria ser somente algo do tipo:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:1000){
rho = c(-0.7,-0.3,0,0.1,0.5) # correlações que preciso utilizar

xstar=rnorm(1000,0,1) # x* com distribuicao normal N(2,2)

a2=rnorm(1000,0,1) # parametro criado para obter w a partir da correlacao rho com x*

w = rho[i]*xstar+sqrt(1-rho[i]^2)*a2 # w calculado a partir de uma correlacao definida com x

corr[j,i]=cor(xstar,w) # matriz de correlacoes entre x* e w
  }
 }
```

Entretanto, note que eu alterei as variáveis para normais com média zero e desvio-padrão um, pois esta fórmula que você está usando `w = rho[k]*xstar+sqrt(1-rho[k]^2)*a2` somente serve para Normal(0,1).

Para gerar múltiplas variáveis arbitrariamente relacionadas, você pode usar o pacote `MASS`. No caso da normal, você pode usar a função `mvrnorm`, ficaria algo do tipo:

```
rho = c(-0.7,-0.3,0,0.1,0.5) 
library(MASS)

### definindo uma função para gerar variáveis correlacionadas
### rho é a correlação, mu é o vetor de médias, e var o vetor de variâncias
sim.cor <- function(rho,mu=c(2,2), var=c(2,2), n=1000, sim=1000){
  correlacoes <- vector(length=sim)
  cov <- rho*sqrt(var[1])*sqrt(var[2])
  for (i in 1:sim){
    simulacao <- mvrnorm(n=n, mu=mu, Sigma=matrix(c(var[1],cov, cov, var[2]), ncol=2))
    correlacoes[i] <- cor(simulacao[,1], simulacao[,2])
  }
  correlacoes
}

### aplicando a função para cada rho
resultados <- mapply(sim.cor, rho)
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda! consegui fazer o que precisava!